# JavaFX - How can I fill with color a shape?

Tags: colors, javafx, geometry, shapes

Let's say that I have an application window and I declare `Circle c = new Circle(40,40,40);`, which is initially black. What should I do if I want to fill it with red?

What should I do if I want to fill it with red? (for example, if a button is clicked, then `c` becomes red)

Answer (score 17):

[Set a fill](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/shape/Shape.html#setFill-javafx.scene.paint.Paint-) on the shape (Java 8 code):

```
Circle circle = new Circle(40, 40, 40); 
Button button = new Button("Red");
button.setOnAction(e -> circle.setFill(javafx.scene.paint.Color.RED));
```

Comment: I tryed but I got this error messagge: Incompatible types: Color cannot be converted to Paint, on the command circle.setFill(Color.RED)

Comment: You are importing `java.awt.Color` instead of `javafx.scene.paint.Color`